# Automatically create the related model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With SqlAlchemy, I have a 1-1 relation defined:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Profile(Base):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

I'd like to enforce the relation so that if a User is created, the Profile is created automatically.

Any way to do it with SqlAlchemy?

Comment: Not sure but maybe if you define an `__init__` method for each class and then call the `UserProfile` init from the `User` one? Psuedo-code `class User: def __init__(): profile = UserProfile()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, name):
        prof = Profile(self, name)
        session.add(prof)
        session.commit()

class Profile(Base):
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.did), primary_key=True)  # you have what I assume is a typo here User.did should probably be User.id
    name = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, user, name):
        user_id = user.id
        self.name = name
```

This works for me with no errors. Provided your `session` object is created in the same file as your classes. If not you might have problems importing it as you may encounter a circular import problem.

Comment: Works on INSERT, but fails on update with the following erorr: "Dependency rule tried to blank-out primary key column 'profile.user_id' on instance '<Profile at 0x4169fd0>'"

Comment: As usual: `user = session.query(User).one() ; user.name = 'IanAuld' ; session.add(user) ; session.commit()`

Comment: Sorry, there is another error with this: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_profile_pkey"

Comment: Is Base created with `declarative_base()`?

Comment: Yes. Hm, tried with a clean project and it works. Seems like some peculiarity is messing here. Thanks, the solution turned out to be quite simple :)